# How do I find out how many simultaneous h264 videos a given graphics card can render?

Tags: video, graphics-card, ffmpeg

We would like to make a single screen presentation of our live feed of up to 60 HD tv channels similar to this old video showing 12 SD channels.  We have done this in software on a suitably powerful server but would like to look into hardware accellerating it and was wondering what current high-end GPU's can do?

[image]
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ig6MpUsXyiY

Unfortunately I have not been able to find out what this technique is called, and my efforts so far have found "merge many displays into a video wall" solutions which is the opposite of what I am looking for.

So, what am I to look for to find out how many HD feeds a given graphics card can render, and is there a good choice (as of now) for doing so?

Comment: Does it have to be the GPU? Because this sort of "effect" could easily be done with FFplay. Also, would it be an option to merge the videos into one and stream them? That way, FFmpeg could easily work with GPU acceleration and the player-computer wouldn't need much ressources.

Comment: @flolilolilo There is no option to merge the videos yet.   We want to not only drink from the firehose but show it too.   Will FFplay be able to cope with 60 simultaneous HD streams?

Comment: I'm sorry - forget about FFplay. I shouldn't write when not yet filled up with coffee! ;-) FFplay won't work with >1 input-stream ("file") at a time. **Question:** Can you pre-render the sequence or does it have to be shown from the files in realtime? If pre-rendering is okay, you can try a blend of [FFmpeg's splitscreen-Wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20mosaic%20out%20of%20several%20input%20videos) and [FFmpeg's HWAccelIntro-Wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro) to pre-create the file. Also, check [FFmpeg's Streaming Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide)

Comment: @flolilolilo Sorry, I thought it was obvious that this was to be real time.

Comment: Okay. Woud streaming (server -> computer  - or same machine but between different programs) be an option?

Comment: @flolilolilo We can probably do stuff.  The problem here is getting the video streams decoded and rendered on a screen - then the "convert to video stream" step is well solved by the gaming community.  Hence the question about GPU ability.  I would be very interested in hearing your suggestions if they focus on how to do hardware assisted rendering of multiple HD streams.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? You get the streams *how* - via ethernet or via an AJA KONA or ...? *What do you want to do* with the splitscreen-stream you render and *which properties* (zero latency, fullHD, quicktime-player-compliance,...) does it need to have? *What hardware* do you have? As it is, this question cannot be answered because I can only guess at those things: `We can probably do stuff` is a case in point.

Comment: We have 60 HD semi-live ethernet transport streams (from a provider - they can be rendered by VLC).  We would like a single semi-live stream containing all these as live miniatures which we can view on computer monitors in-house.  My idea was to have one or more GPU render these as a HDMI output which another device could then convert to a suitable ethernet stream.

Answer (score 0):

Considering there is no specific software for your purpose*, I will try to answer this from an FFmpeg point of view.

<sub>* There are some, but those are professional and therefore relatively pricy. Typically, one would accomplish such a thing with a (semi-)hardware-solution, though I have to admit: I never needed more than a 2*2 grid myself.</sub>

I assume the following things:

- Input-Streams have an aspect ratio of 16:9 **and should be left that way** (i.e. no cropping)
- Output-Stream has an aspect ratio of 16:9, too
- Both input-streams and the output-stream are FullHD (1920x1080 px)
- Hardware-capabilities are unlimited (meaning: I can't test my answer as I do not have 60 input-streams and/or the same hardware as you.)

---

#### Splitscreen

If you do not want to crop away anything of any inputs and the aspect ratio of both the inputs and the output is the same, you can go with a grid of n*n streams. Since 8*8=64 is the smallest grid to fit all inputs, we will go with that. 4 grid-spaces will not be filled - you could spare them out in the middle or on the corners (I will go with the latter one).

```cs
-filter_complex "
    nullsrc=size=1920x1080[base];
    [0:v]scale=w=in_w/8:h=in_h/8[0_1];
    [1:v]scale=w=in_w/8:h=in_h/8[0_1];
    [2:v]scale=w=in_w/8:h=in_h/8[0_2];
    [3:v]scale=w=in_w/8:h=in_h/8[0_3];
    <<AND SO ON>>
    [59:v]scale=w=in_w/8:h=in_h/8[7_6];
    [base][0_1]overlay=x=240:y=0[tmp0];
    [tmp0][0_2]overlay=x=480:y=0[tmp1];
    <<AND SO ON>>
    [tmp9][1_2]overlay=x=480:y=135[tmp10];
    <<AND SO ON>>
    [tmp58][7_6]overlay=x=1440:y=945
"
```

You could omit the `scale`-part if the input-streams are already in the correct size for your grid: if that is an option, I'd suggest doing so.

---

#### Streams (both in and out)

Should be the easiest part, though it is the one part that I really can't say much about. [FFmpeg's StreamingGuide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide#Pointtopointstreaming) has some ideas about it:

On the input-side:

```
# Using TCP:
ffmpeg -i tcp://host:port?listen
# Using RTSP:
ffmpeg -rtsp_flags listen rtsp://host:port/live.sdp?tcp
```

On the output-side:

```
# For TCP:
ffmpeg -i INPUT -f mpegts tcp://host:port
# For UDP:
ffmpeg -i INPUT -f mpegts udp://host:port
# For RTSP (using TCP instead of UDP):
ffmpeg -i input -f rtsp -rtsp_transport tcp rtsp://host:port/live.sdp
```

[FFmpeg's documentation links this website - it includes an example of a transcoding from RTMP to RTMP.](https://sonnati.wordpress.com/2011/08/30/ffmpeg-%E2%80%93-the-swiss-army-knife-of-internet-streaming-%E2%80%93-part-iv/)

---

#### Acceleration, latency

[FFmpeg's StreamingGuide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide#Pointtopointstreaming) suggests the following settings:

```cs
-c:v libx264 -tune zerolatency -preset ultrafast
```

Those seem quite reasonable, as they will probably not have too much impact on your latency. If you want, you could try other codecs (x265 has a zerolatency-option, too).
If there's a chance that any of the input-streams has an autio-stream, `-an` will be a good idea as it will omit all auio and therefore it's one encoder less to worry about.

Now if you want to go the GPU-route, there isn't much I can tell you without knowing the exact model of GPU you have. [FFmpeg's HWAccelIntro-Wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro) can probably help you.
I for one wouldn't bother with it - I can't even get my GTX970 to behave well with two input-streams (I assume it's because GPGPUs are not made for multitasking, *but this is an unsupported claim*) and the `h264_nvenc` on `-preset fast` is considerably slower than `libx264` on `-preset ultrafast`. Even if it works, things start to get messy, fast: the stream will be bloated (in comparison to x264) and blocking-artifacts are quite common.

---

### Adding all of it together

```cs
# Calling FFmpeg, getting inputs:
ffmpeg -i tcp://host:port?listen <<REPEAT 59 TIMES>>
# Create the splitscreen:
    -filter_complex "<<TAKE THE FILTER FROM ABOVE>>"
# Encoding-options:
    -an -c:v libx264 -tune zerolatency -preset ultrafast
# Output as stream:
    -f mpegts tcp://host:port
```

Of course, you have to fill in the blank parts and remove the comments.

---

#### Conclusion

That should be the FFmpeg-approach to your problem. You will have to try it out to find out if it works, I'm sorry for that. But the code in itself should work - and if the hardware (especially the network's bandwidth) isn't holding you back, this approach should work just fine on any relatively new processor.